# js infer inherited static property from class name

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
abstract class Model{
    static name
}

class Book extends Model {
    static name = Book.constructor.name
}
```

Is there some way to automatically set the static property name based on `Book.constructor.name` without specifying it in the child class? I.e. can I tell the Model class to always have name equal to the child class constructor name?

Comment: This is not valid JS syntax at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want `Book.name` to be `"Book"`, you don't have to do anything about that - it exists by default. I don't think you want to use `Book.constructor.name` anywhere (which is `"Function"`).